# What is the hierarchy of WCMS?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I think module and hierarchy in **WCMS** are different .So what will be the proper answer for  hierarchy of **WCMS** ?
Please answer

Comment: I can't understand your question. We have also steps creating something in WCMS.

Comment: Check this : https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/everything-about-wcms-in-hybris/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is not very clear. There is no hierarchy concept in WCMS. For me WCMS is a module and the module is composed of extensions.

So I guess the question is what are the extensions relations/*hierarchy*?

It's described in [WCMS Module](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8c82617c86691014abcda90cb5da8465.html) documentation

[image]

*This image comes from the SAP documentation referenced in above link.*

Comment: Thank you for clearing my misunderstanding about the concept.